# Hibernate runs query but who is the caller

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

Is there a way to identify the caller of a query that I see Hibernate is running? The query is repeated many times but I cannot identify who is calling it and it is creating a lot of tension on the CPU.

The query is roughly the following:

```
select [...] 
from schema.Table0 table0_ 
left outer join schema.File file1_ on table0_.file_sid=file1_.sid 
left outer join schema.Table2 tbl2_ on table0_.table2_end_sid=tbl2_.sid 
left outer join schema.File file3_ on tbl2_.file_sid=file3_.sid 
left outer join schema.Table2 tbl4_ on table0_.table2_start_sid=tbl4_.sid 
left outer join schema.Flow flow5_ on table0_.flow_sid=flow5_.sid     

left outer join schemaFlow flow6_ on flow5_.parent_flow=flow6_.sid 
left outer join schema.Message message7_ on    
table0_.message_sid=message7_.sid left outer join schemaFlow flow8_ on 
message7_.flow_sid=flow8_.sid 
left outer join schema.Lang lang9_ on message7_.lang=lang9_.code left  
outer join schema.Table0 table10_ on table0_.parent=table10_.sid where   
table0_.sid=1
```

Comment: What is the query? Are you sure it's not a test-on-idle validation query?

Comment: It is a query that apparently is produced by JPA because it is not one of the native ones I have written. But it is not a test-on-idle because it queries a bunch of my tables with left out joins and a where clause at the end

Comment: Assuming you have X candidates that use the relevant hiberate object, you could try eliminating half of them at a time by commenting them out and see if the issue is reproduced or not. This way you'll need logX tries to find the criminal.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that on my pc and there is no way to do this in production. I can turn on logging but I don't see the caller of a particular hibernate query.